# How can I simulate batch run in Cloud?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have the following batch functions

```
    @Scheduled(cron="0 15 1 * * ?")
    public void executeJob() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Execute Batch Job : START"); //TODO
            businessOperationAdminService.executeBatchJob(false, BATCH_USERNAME);
            System.out.println("Execute Batch Job : END"); //TODO
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="0 30 1 1 * ?")
    public void executeMonthlyJob() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Execute Monthly Batch Job : START"); //TODO
            businessOperationAdminService.executeMonthlyBatchJob(false, BATCH_USERNAME);
            System.out.println("Execute Monthly Batch Job : END"); //TODO
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The app is running in Cloud services where I have no control over the timezone. Now I'd like to test how the result will look like lets say after I run the batches 30 times. The issue is now I can't simply change the server time and rerun the app.

What's the best way to test this kind of batch jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental idea about using annotated POJOs (plain old java objects) is that, being objectsfof a class just like any other, you can test them just like any other. So if you want to test what happens after 30 months have gone by and so the monthly job has jun 30 times... you simply call `executeMonthlyJob` 30 times in your test.